# Get Assembly version on windows phone 7

Tags: reflection, windows-phone-7

In my c# applications I usually get the version (to show the customer) using the following code:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

This does not work in Windows Phone 7 (it hangs the emulator, and phone crashing is a no-no for MS).

So, how do I get the version of the executing on a windows phone 7 device??

[Update] as noted in the comments below, calling GetName() in a wp7 app seems to be the problem.

Comment: I would definitely report this to Microsoft. Your code is correct, and the hanging is definitely caused by a bug either in the .NET in the emulator, or in the whole .NET for WP7!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private static string GetVersionNumber()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var parts = asm.FullName.Split(',');
        return parts[1].Split('=')[1];
    }
```

Comment: Well, this is essentially the same I wrote above, and it hangs the phone just like my version does.

Comment: @Sam this is working for me in apps in the Marketplace. I had to parse the version number out of the FullName as `Version` wasn't working for me. What error are you getting?

Comment: Aah, I checked back, I did not use FullName, but GetName instead. And whenever I have a call to GetName in my app, the emulator, device and debugger just hang - not when the GetName is hit, but when the app is started!

Comment: So even when GetName is not called, just its existence in the code is enough to crash the program. #Strange

Comment: A post on it : http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2011/11/07/wp7-how-to-get-the-version-number-of-my-application/

Comment: `GetName()` is marked as `SecurityCritical` while `FullName` isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Does parsing it out of

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName

work for you?

example output: SomeApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

edit: don't need to go through ManifestModule

Comment: I don't even get that far: it seems use of reflection kills the phone.

Comment: Testing on Samsung Taylor prototype device           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);... no probs.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I mistakenly used GetName instead of FullName.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it's more apt to use the assembly's file version info for conveying the application version to the user. See http://techblog.ranjanbanerji.com/post/2008/06/26/Net-Assembly-Vs-File-Versions.aspx

Second, what about doing this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

public static class AssemblyExtensions
{
    public static Version GetFileVersion(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        var versionString = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(false)
            .OfType<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>()
            .First()
            .Version;

        return Version.Parse(versionString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem there is that it returns the particular string set in AssemblyInfo.cs, which means if you wildcard revision and build, you get something like "1.2.*" instead of "1.2.3.4"

Comment: According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyfileversionattribute.assemblyfileversionattribute.aspx) wildcards are not supported for AssemblyFileVersionAttribute, and doing so will emit a compiler warning because it's meaningless in this context. Use of wildcards for the version is only applicable to AssemblyVersion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.assemblyversionattribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string GetVersion()
    {
        return Regex.Match(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, @"Version=(?<version>[\d\.]*)").Groups["version"].Value;
    }
```

is fairly clean as well.